# Decode aac audio file with ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

how to decode the AAC format audio file(i.e. 1.aac) into pcm or wav file with ffmpeg command?

Comment: What have you tried? There's documentation at: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html. Are you having specific issues at any stage? If so, detail those specific issues in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question fit for superuser.com.

Here is your answer
ffmpeg -i input.aac out.wav